# failed to run git bash on win7 64bit

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm new to git. 
I installed the latest version of msysgit on my computer. But when I tried to use git bash, it turned out like this:

```
0 [main] sh.exe" 5132 fork_copy:user/cygwin data pass 0 failed,0x47F000.

.0x4843DC, done 232, windows pid 4132, win32 error 5

sh.exe": fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
sh.exe"-3.1$
```

I reinstall it but the problem persists. And I also try other version, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Which version number is "the latest version"? (ie to know if you're running a preview/beta/release/...?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have got the same issue:

`sh.exe" 8144 fork_copy: user/cygwin data pass 0 failed, 0x47F000..0x4843DC, done 236, windows pid 7912, Win32 error 5`

I've also uninstalled the anti-virus software from baidu.com, and now everything is ok.

So, I think maybe you can try to check the anti-virus software.

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried closing the anti-virus software but it didn't work. Then I downloaded a portable git and surprisingly it works well. And it's worth mentioning that I also use the anti-virus software from baidu.com, and it seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I upgrade to the lastest version of msysgit and tortoisegit [msysgit (Git-1.9.0-preview20140217.exe) 和 tgit(TortoiseGit-1.8.7.0-32bit.msi)],that fixed my probelm. 
you can try.

others : you can try close your Anti-virus software.

Answer (score 0):

Win versions of git have an internal mingw or cygwin, which is incompatible with the officisl mingw/cygwin implementations, mainly on small but important version problems.

But it is not a big problem, because this official mingw/cygwin implementations contains also their git, which is well integrated into the another parts of their system.

My personal opinion: Mingwin has a lot of incompatible subversions, and its only advantage (good integration with the win32 api with a small footstep) is long over. The best to do currently if you use cygwin, and let it the only single unix api on your system  (to avoid compat problems).